# Why after the Div the quotient in EAX and the remainder in EDX is not modified

Tags: assembly, fasm

I am beginner in ASM, currently i am using FASM and with my code :

```
 include 'win32ax.inc'

.code

start:

    XOR     EDX,EDX      ; set to 0
    MOV     EBX,22
;@DivLoop:
    MOV     EAX,7
    DIV     EBX
```

For Debug i am using Ollydbg and like you can see the register is not modified.

[Ollydbg screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTJGc.png)

I would like to understand why is not modified.
Thanks You very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That screenshot is showing that 7/16 = 0 with a remainder of 7; which is exactly what you'd expect.

Both registers (`EAX` and `EDX`) did change (`EAX` changed from 7 to 0, and `EDX` changed from 0 to 7).

Comment: Hello Thanks you. you are great i was lost